# How include a library downloaded in C?

Tags: c, include-path

i'm trying to build an old project in C.

It includes this package:

```c
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
```

However, VSCode says that it can't open this file.
I checked the in directory `/usr/include/` and there was no such library so I installed it with

```bash
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0
```

I checked and the file `/usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h` now exists but I'm getting the same error in VSCode and the compilation doesn't work.

So, my question is how `#include` works.  Specifically, which directories does it search?

Comment: Hm, if it's in `/usr/include`, then it should work.  That's strange.

Comment: `gcc -xc -E -v -` should give you the searched paths. Also try restarting VSCode and bash after lib install

Comment: Try restarting the system and VSCode.

Comment: I try to restart, still got error.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian stable (as you mention `apt` above):

1. `sudo apt install libusb-1.0-0-dev`
2. Update your build configuration to use `pkg-config --cflags libusb-1.0` when compiling your program, and `pkg-config --libs libusb-1.0` when you link it.
3. Update your program to eliminate the path prefix  `#include <libusb.h>`

Never used VSCode but maybe it requires `\` for paths?  If it didn't include `/usr/include` in it's include search path nothing would compile.

Comment: I switched from Linux Mint to Ubuntu and now it works.